# What is this plant with small red bell shaped flowers?

Tags: identification

Could you please identify this plant. All I know is that it is blooming with small red "bells".

[image]

Comment: Please ask a separate question for each plant that you want identified. Thanks!

Comment: This plant has no blooms at all - do you mean it should bloom with red bells rather than it is blooming, or is this the wrong photo?

Comment: @Bamboo Yes, I meant it should bloom :)

Comment: Can I just ask one question, even though you've accepted an answer - is the main stem woody, or soft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a [Fuchsia sp.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchsia) and quite a young one. I can also tell you that this baby wants to be moved outside, in a semi-shaded place, because it shows signs of [etiolation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiolation), AKA lack of light.

Come fall before the first frost, move it indoors, cut back a bit and overwinter in a cool place. If neccessary it can even go in a dark place where it will loose all leaves, but will re-grow them in Spring. Move out as soon as possible but take it back inside at night until the last frost because it shouldn't get any frost.

There are a few hardy varieties, but they typically have narrower leaves and smallish flowers. This looks like the classic Fuchsia hybrid - and there are *lots* of these on the market.

You can easily propagate your fuchsia from cuttings. I recomend letting them develop roots in a jar of water (my preferred method, it's basically fail-safe and I simply use the "leftovers" from pruning...), but putting them straight into the ground works, too, according to various sources. In this case, a heating pad below might speed things up a bit.

Keep an eye out for aphids and especially whiteflies, If neccessary, treat accordingly.